# How do I configure a Belkin n52te gamepad to work?

Tags: 13.10, gamepad

I was wondering how I could possibly get my Belkin n52te gamepad working on this version of Ubuntu - ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Install Monitoring and Remapping Application Needed for the Driver**

It is ***Pystromo***. It has to be download from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/pystromo).

Press Ctrl+Alt+T to open terminal. Run these commands one by one in terminal;

```
cd ~/Downloads

sudo wget "https://launchpadlibrarian.net/18545559/pystromo-0.6.0.tar.gz"

sudo sed -i '$a uinput' /etc/modules

sudo modprobe uinput

tar -xvf pystromo-0.6.0.tar.gz

sudo cp pystromo/config/52-pystromo-debian.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/

sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

sudo udevadm trigger

mv pystromo ~/.config/

cp ~/.config/pystromo/config/* ~/.config/pystromo/

cp ~/.config/pystromo/lib/* ~/.config/pystromo/

sed -r 's:config/:~/.config/pystromo/config/:g' -i ~/.config/pystromo/monitor.conf

sudo python ~/.config/pystromo/pystromo-mon.py
```

In order to start it at boot,

- Type "*Startup Applications*" in dash, select it and open.
- Then Click on "Add" button.
- In the new window, type "Pystromo" in *Name* field, and type "sudo python ~/.config/pystromo/pystromo-mon.py" in *Command* field. Then click on "Add" button.

Then you have to install the device driver.

**2. Install Device Driver**

It is ***Nostromo***. You need to have Sun's Java JRE 1.6 installed to run it.

Can download Jnostromo from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnostromo/?source=directory). After download install it with,

```
cd ~/Downloads

chmod +x jnostromo-1.5.2-linux-installer.run

sudo ./jnostromo-1.5.2-linux-installer.run
```

Driver installation prompt will start. After installation, you can run it with jnostromo Icon in desktop.(You need Sun's java JRE versionn 1.6)

Comment: Thank you, however at the end I get 

`WARNING: Unable to load "/home/jev/.config/pystromo/monitor.conf"`

Comment: There was some mistakes in that article as well as in that file. I corrected them. Run `sudo rm -r ~/.config/pystromo` and repeat the whole process.

Comment: I downloaded the file and after typing in `sudo sh jnostromo-1.5.2-linux-installer.run` I get `jnostromo-1.5.2-linux-installer.run: 1: jnostromo-1.5.2-linux-installer.run: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: Sorry, this time I done a mistake. Use `sudo ./jnostromo-1.5.2-linux-installer.run` instead of `sudo sh jnostromo-1.5.2-linux-installer.run`. Driver installation Prompt will start.

Comment: OK! I got it up and running. Now trying to figure out how to get it to recognize my device and I'll be good to go lol