# Belkin n52te driver install

Tags: drivers, usb

I tried fallowing this thread [How do I configure a Belkin n52te gamepad to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362843/how-do-i-configure-a-belkin-n52te-gamepad-to-work) and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=948833 to get my Belkin n52te to work. neither of which worked.

when I did the ubuntuforums way I got this error "lookuperror no uinput device-nodes found"

using the other I got no hardware found when running the jnostromo.

lsusb gives me 2 different n52te's

Bus 002 Device 011: ID 050d:0200 Belkin Components Nostromo SpeedPad n52te Gaming Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 050d:0415 Belkin Components

I tried switching between these two and neither worked either.

Answer (score 0):

The first link in your post also requires you to manually populate a .map file to program the n52te.  The pystromo-mon.py will read the file in the .config/pystromo directory and make the n52te use those keys.  Alot of trial and error on my part was needed to make it work but I have my n52 and n52 running just fine now that I know what to do.

I have been in contact in the past with a developer who has made a tournament authorized programming tool w/gui for the Nostromo gamepads, along with the Razer version..

Here is a link to his site. http://sourceforge.net/projects/kbmaster/

Hope that helps!